# Why tkinter filedialog not opening file dialog box when the code is inside the function in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a python console menu app. I want to select a CSV file from the user file location and need to ask the user to select the file location. I'm trying it with tkinter filedialog. But it working fine when it is outside of the function. But when I put the code lines into a function it is not opening the file dialog box.

**This is what I tried,**

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def menu():

    print(" Please select item from the menu ")

    choice = int(input("""
           1: Upload new file
           2. Read file 
           0: Exit
           Please enter your choice: """))

    if choice == 1:
        upload_file()
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Please try again")
        #read_file()
    elif choice == 0:
        print("Exit.")
        sys.exit
    else:
        print("Please try again")
        menu()


def upload_file():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    print(file_path)

menu()
```

It is not showing any error or something. Also need to check user selects the CSV file or not. if it is not a CSV file ask the user to select the correct file.
Please Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. If you want to limit selection to csv simply add `file_types` argument to `askopenfilename` - `askopenfilename(filetypes=[("CSV", "*.csv")])`

Comment: the problem is code is working fine if I put it outside of the function. But it is not open the file dialog box when coding in the function.

Comment: it also works when debugging. I don't know why this is not working.

Comment: Then maybe provide the code that is **not working**? How are we supposed to guess what is wrong with it without seeing the code?

Comment: I already add my all code line in the question

Comment: In that case, let me repeat: **that code works**. If it doesn't work for you, you need to provide more information, e.g. how are you running it.

Comment: I'm using pycharm to code and run the code. I used green play button to run the the program.

Comment: In that case I don't know what to tell you. I copied your code, started it, got greeted with: "Please select item from the menu 1: Upload new file..." and after typing 1 I got the file dialog.

Answer (score 1):

As said by matszwecja, the code works fine for me too.

You can check if the selected file ends with .csv with this simple bit, it keeps asking to select again until a csv file is selected by checking if the whole file path ends with ".csv".

Let me know if you still need help.

```
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    if not file_path.endswith(".csv"):
        print("Invalid file type. Please select a CSV file.")
        upload_file()
    else:
        print(file_path)
    exit
```

Also you can just use "exit" instead of the sys.exit, which doesn't work without importing sys and bracket, sys.exit().

Comment: Just use `file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename("Select file",(("CSV Files","*.csv"),))` : it will only open csv files, no need to check the extension.